# Why i get wrap socket error message when sending an email through python 2023?

Tags: python-3.x, gmail, smtplib

im trying to send an email throiugh python from my gmail email address

I followed the instructions from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_j6ILT-X0k

but i get the following error message (that is not showed in the video)

line 33, in 
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as smtp:
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\smtplib.py", line 1050, in **init**
SMTP.**init**(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout,
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\smtplib.py", line 255, in **init**
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\smtplib.py", line 1057, in _get_socket
new_socket = self.context.wrap_socket(new_socket,
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket'

Here is my code:

```
import os
from email.message import EmailMessage
import ssl
import smtplib

# Email details
email_sender = 'xxx@gmail.com'
email_password = 'PUT YOUR PASSWORD'  
email_receiver = 'bbbb@gmail.com'

subject='Sample Email'


# Email body
body = """
Hello,

This is a sample email.

Best regards,
Your Name
"""


em = EmailMessage()
em['From'] = email_sender
em['To'] = email_receiver
em['Subject'] =  subject
em.set_content(body)

context = ssl.create_default_context

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as smtp:
    smtp.login(email_sender, email_password)
    smtp.sendmail(email_sender, email_receiver, em.as_string())
```

Thanks